# How to specify distance metric while for kmeans in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm doing kmeans clustering in R with two requirements:

1. I need to specify my own distance function, now it's Pearson Coefficient.
2. I want to do the clustering that uses average of group members as centroids, rather some actual member.
   The reason for this requirement is that I think using average as centroid makes more sense than using an actual member since the members are always not near the real centroid. Please correct me if I'm wrong about this.

First I tried the `kmeans` function in `stat` package, but this function doesn't allow custom distance method.

Then I found `pam` function in `cluster` package. The `pam` function does allow custom distance metric by taking a `dist` object as parameter, but it seems to me that by doing this it takes actual members as centroids, which is not what I expect. Since I don't think it can do all the distance computation with just a distance matrix.

So is there some easy way in R to do the kmeans clustering that satisfies both my requirements ?

Comment: You can use `vegan::designdist` to create your own index (also see `vegan::vegdist` if it's already there). After you have your `dist` object, you can use `hclust` in stats package to use your appropriate method of aggregation.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, thanks for commenting. I know how to specify distance metric with hclust, but now I need to know how to do it with kmeans.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check the [`flexclust`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexclust/index.html) package:

> The main function `kcca` implements a general framework for
>   k-centroids cluster analysis supporting arbitrary distance measures
>   and centroid computation.

The package also includes a function `distCor`:

```
R> flexclust::distCor
function (x, centers) 
{
    z <- matrix(0, nrow(x), ncol = nrow(centers))
    for (k in 1:nrow(centers)) {
        z[, k] <- 1 - .Internal(cor(t(x), centers[k, ], 1, 0))
    }
    z
}
<environment: namespace:flexclust>
```

Comment: Thanks rcs ! Why do I get "incompatible dimension" error when I specify dist as : family=kccaFamily(dist=function(x, y) { 1 - cor(x,y) }) ?

Comment: You need a function with arguments `x` and `centers`. See for instance the source code of `flexclust::distCor`

Comment: In case anyone is confused on how to use distCor, try: `res = kcca(data, 10, family=kccaFamily(dist=distCor))`

Comment: As an R rookie, it also took me a while to figure out how to see what attributes `res` had (use `attributes(res)` to determine, and `attr(res, 'second')` to access one.